# How do I computer average into a method?

Tags: java

I'm attempting to call a method in order to calculate average (calcavgnow)..  I'm trying to have it calculate the average of all the numbers in the array and return the average to the caller.  I'm hoping it can deal with any size array.  I tried attempting below.. can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class sdasfs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double total = 0;
        double SelectNumber = 0;
        int a = 0;
        double calcavgnow = 0;

        do {
            try {
                String UserInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount of numbers you would like to average");
                SelectNumber = Integer.parseInt(UserInput);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Value must be an integer!");
            }
        } while (SelectNumber < 1);

        double Numbers[] = new double[(int) SelectNumber];

        for (a = 0; a < Numbers.length; a++) {
            String EnterNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number.");
            Numbers[a] = Double.parseDouble(EnterNumber);

            total += Numbers[a];
            calcavgnow = total / SelectNumber;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getTotal(numbers) + " divided by " + Numbers.length + " is " + getAvg(Numbers));
    }


        //Create method in order to calculate calcavgnow

       public static double getAvg(int numbers[]){
          return (double)getTotal(numbers)/numbers.length;
       }

       public static int getTotal(int numbers[]){
          int total = 0;
          for(int i:numbers)
              total +=i;
          return total;
       }
    }// end class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a separate method to calculate average. Don't do everything inside the same method. Learn to modularize your code. So others can easily get adopt to your code.

```
public static double getAvg(double numbers[]){
     return getTotal(numbers)/numbers.length;
}

public static double getTotal(double numbers[]){
   double total = 0;
   for(double i:numbers)
       total +=i;
   return total;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help.  So I'm trying to call the method within my Pop up as shown here:

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average entered is " + getAvg);

But i'm getting an error.  How do you properly call it?

Comment: pass your array to that method like this
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average entered is " + getAvg(Numbers));

Comment: I'm getting the error.. "The method getAvg(int[]) in the type sdasfs is not applicable for the arguments (double[])".  I will post my current code in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class AvgCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double total = 0;
        double SelectNumber = 0;
        int a = 0;
        double calcavgnow = 0;

        do {
            try {
                String UserInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount of numbers you would like to average");
                SelectNumber = Integer.parseInt(UserInput);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Value must be an integer!");
            }
        } while (SelectNumber < 1);

        double Numbers[] = new double[(int) SelectNumber];

        for (a = 0; a < Numbers.length; a++) {
            String EnterNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number.");
            Numbers[a] = Double.parseDouble(EnterNumber);

            total += Numbers[a];

        }
        calcavgnow = total / SelectNumber;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average entered is " + calcavgnow);
    }
}
```